# How do I transfer a photo in Preview to iPhoto?

Tags: macos, photos.app, preview

I have a Photo in Preview.  How do I move it to iPhoto?

Answer (score 1):

There's numerous methods:

- Drag the photo from Preview (press ⌥⌘2 to show thumbnails) to iPhoto's main window, or on the Dock.
- Drag the photo from its location to iPhoto's main window, or on the Dock.
- Go to iPhoto and select File → Import to Library and select the location of the photo.

Comment: And my favourite one: drag the proxy icon (the little icon beside the document title in the Preview title bar) into iPhoto.

Answer (score -1):

I moved it to desk top and then dragged it to i photo.